# Add songs to FireFoxOS simulator

Tags: firefox, simulator, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-os

Anyone know how to add song files to FireFox OS simulator? Is it Possible or not?
I enabled the USB storage in the simulator. But now it showing Media Storage 0B is available.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I got it [limitations of firefox simulator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Firefox_OS_Simulator#Limitations_of_the_Sim%20%20ulator)

Thanks...

Comment: MP3, AAC, H.264 (MP4) and WebM are not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu and by placing the mp3 files in the home/Music/ directory I was able add the mp3 files to FireFox OS simulator. But when I tried playing the files the music app crashed! Maybe you'll have better luck with that!